# Is it possible to pass arguments from a Microsoft Flow action to a Flow Connector

Tags: automation, power-automate

I have a connector and I'd like to pass the hostname as an argument from a previous Action to a custom connector in a flow.

Here is where I'd like to parameterize:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: you can find it in dynamic values ? what's the problem ?

Comment: @Balaji dynamic values dont appear when I go into the host input box...